# Authentication not persisting with Claims

Tags: claims-based-auth, windows-authentication

We are using Claims Based Authentication for an application that was upgraded from 2007. It actually uses a custom forms provider for the front-end, but to edit content we use Windows Authentication. We are using the default sign-in page to access the back-end.

We are able to log in using Windows, and everything seems fine. However, as we navigate areas of the admin system we are constantly promoted to re-authenticate. Once we do this we can get to the page, but the extra auth popup/redirect breaks admin functionally such as editing. It seems to happen in specific areas, and sometimes just randomly.

The log file contains many errors such as:

```
The exception occurred while connecting to WCF endpoint: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 
      The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.
```

Does anyone know how to resolve or debug this?